# Visual Studio: Publish application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, download, publish

I made a simple Windows application to test how I can publish my application.
So what I want to know is how can I publish my application so that it creates an installer so that other users around the world can download, install and use my application?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the "setup" project available in visual studio, that creates a MSI file.

Also you may use the publish concept called "click-once-deployment".
Please go through this article that explains the methodology:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/ClickOnce-Deployment.aspx

Comment: Try this one instead: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2006/02/2977/

Answer (score 0):

Create homepage to describe your application information, update somewhere for others to download. Well, you can give a try by creating a site on `CodePlex, SourceForge`...

Answer (score 0):

You could try [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

> ClickOnce deployment allows you to publish Windows-based applications to a Web server or network file share for simplified installation.

You just need to define which prerequisites you want to include in bootstraper, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4k032e1.aspx)